# Can two torrent files use the same source?

Tags: bittorrent

a bit of a complicated question, but maybe easier than I think :)

I was wondering if it's possible to have two seperate torrent files point to the same files. I know that you can seed the exact same files to two separate torrents (cross-seeding) but what I was wondering is the following scenario:

Torrent A contains Folder A and File A, B, and C.

For Torrent B, I only need File A and B and want to place it in Folder B.

Is it possible now to point Torrent B to the files A and B from Folder A or do I need to create a copy of File A and B in Folder B in order to be able to seed these files?

The reason behind this is obviously to avoid redundancy and save disk space, but I wasn't sure if the actual folder of torrent A is included in the hashing process and if each file has a unique hash that can be replicated across multiple torrent files.

Thanks a lot for the help and looking forward to see if this can be achieved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If required files are identical, you can create Folder A and Folder B, place files A, B and C in Folder A and create hard links to files A and B in Folder B. Hard links point to the same file location without using extra drive space.

Hard links can be made with built in system tools.

Comment: This is a good idea, I just checked this and it works very nice. Would there be a problem though when both torrents access the same file or will this not matter as it's the exact same file either way and it just acts out as if I were cross-seeding?

Comment: @Vayaa There shouldn't be any problems while seeding as those are multiple read operations that don't alter these files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Creating the torrent you can just give your client exclusion arguments ("filec.ext") into the GUI and it won't include them. Where the option is varies from client to client.

A backup solution would be to stop torrent A, cut FileC out, make torrent B, paste FileC back in, restart torrent A.

Comment: I see where you are coming from on this one. How do I go about this though when the folder name needs to be different in torrent B? Then I can't just "cheat" the way you mentioned, can I? I suppose if I do, in either case one of the two torrents wouldn't know where the files are located, as the root folder is different in both of them then, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Your client should have a relocate file feature, its very common. It then maps out to where the files actually are. Sym links suggested above work, but may cause problems later following OS upgrades etc and programs that dont support them (Dropbox for example). Thats why I prefer to leave the client manage the pathing.

Comment: I see...I can only see this feature in rtorrent when clicking on the torrent itself and then point the entire torrent to a different folder, but it doesn't seem possible with single files, correct me if I am wrong.